# Get a matching row in database, but select the next one

Tags: sql, mysql

```
id  number  area  order
-----------------------
1   101     10    1
3   102     10    3
17  103     10    4
29  222     11    1
32  332     11    2
53  545     11    3
```

Hi!

When a row is found through `number` I want to select the next row in that same `area` based on `order`.

For example, if I want to know what `number` comes after 222 I want it to return 332, since they are both in the `area` 11 and 222 has `order` 1 and 332 has `order` 2.

Another example is that `number` 102 comes after 101, even though there is a little gap in `order`.

Also:

- The `id` is not necessary in order
- The `number` is not necessary in order and can have gaps
- There can be gaps in `order`

At this time, I solve this with a multi-query:

```sql
SELECT
   @area := area,
   @order := order
FROM <table-name>
WHERE
   number = 222
LIMIT 1;

SELECT
   number
FROM <table-name>
WHERE
   area = @area
   AND order > @order
ORDER BY
   order
LIMIT 1;
```

Solution below would solve it in a single query, but it doesn't really scream *efficience*:

```sql
SELECT
   number
FROM <table-name>
WHERE
   area = ( -- Get area from number
      SELECT
         area
      FROM <table-name>
      WHERE
         number = 222
      LIMIT 1
   )
   AND order > ( -- Get order from number
      SELECT
         order
      FROM <table-name>
      WHERE
         number = 222
      LIMIT 1
   )
ORDER BY
   order
LIMIT 1;
```

Is there an efficient way of solving this with a single query?

PS. Ignore the fact that there is a column named `order`, it's just in this example =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window function `LEAD()` can be used to get next value :

```
select next_number
from (
  select *, lead(number) over (partition by area order by `order`) as next_number
  from mytable
) as s
where number = 222
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I had to add pharentesis around `select *, lead(number) over (partition by area order by order)` to make it work, otherwise it was flawless!

Comment: Glad to hear :)